# lookupReference is not working in config property update method

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a trouble with using 'lookupReference' method.

I have a panel with config.

```
Ext.define('TestPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mypanel',
    referenceHolder: true,
    config: { value: null },
    items: [{ xtype: 'textfield', reference: 'name'}],
    updateValue: function(value) {
        this.lookupReference('name').setValue(value);
    }
});
```

And when I create a panel as follow

```
Ext.widget('mypanel', {value: 1});
```

I get error because `this.lookupReference('name')` in panel's updateValue method is null.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1p2a)

How to use 'lookupReference' in update method?

Thanks.

Comment: When inside the updateValue function this likely refers to the html document, so i assume you are in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `updateValue` is called before the component is rendered.

You can wait for `afterrender`: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1p2i

Comment: I created a function for call update on afterrender

`callAfterRender: function (view) {
            if (view.rendered) {
                return false;
            }

            var fn = arguments.callee.caller;

            view.un('afterrender', fn, view);
            view.on('afterrender', fn.apply.bind(fn, view, fn.arguments), null, { single: true });
            return true;
        }`. And I am using this function in update functions `if (callAfterRender(this)) { return; }`

Comment: @CD.. Could you explain the code in your fiddle? Why is there a `return` on line 21? And what is the syntax `this.updateValue.bind(this, value)` actually doing?

Comment: The `return` is there just to avoid going on to line 24.
The [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Your example solved my problem, by the way. So double thank you!